# Meaning of "out" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> A girl ran **out** in front of my car.

I believe it equals -

> "A girl ran into the road in front of my car."

But, I don't understand the use of "out" here.

Comment: *into the road*? Are you sure?

Comment: Like Maulik V pointed out in his answer, it would be better if we could have the context.

Comment: @MaulikV  *Run into something* means to collide with it if the something is a solid object, but to run *into* the road means to run to a location in (or on) the road, just as to run *into* a room means to run to a location inside the room.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm clear about *run into*. But *run into road* sounded a bit odd. Anyway, thanks for your kind input.

Comment: @MaulikV I can see how it would sound odd. We think of the road here as a place, not an object.

Comment: I can imagine some contexts that both sentences can be used to refer to the same event. I was in my car, and the girl was locked up in another car. Then somehow she managed to escape, and ran out. She ran into the road, risking her life, trying to get to the other side of the road where I parked my car. And there she was. she was standing in front of my car, now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this construction is somewhat colloquial. In all likelihood the 'out' could be dropped and the meaning of the sentence would not change.

The sentence could be broken down in two ways:

1. "Ran out" as a phrasal verb, implying the girl ran from inside something (a house?), and "in front of" as a preposition telling where she ran out to.
2. "Out in front of" as a preposition, meaning in front of, but some distance away from the front of the car.

Perhaps the author had interpretation #1 in mind, to make it clear the girl was not running on the road with the car, but had run into the car's path.

Answer (score 0):

> A girl ran out in front of my car.

The context here could have helped me clarifying it better but whatever the case, I think...

This simply means that a girl came (running) out from some place (maybe, a building) and she was right in front of your car.

Comment: Somehow, that doesn't quite seem right. From your point of view the sentence should have been " A girl came running out to the front of my car."

Comment: @AdilAli No: *to the front of* means *to [the front part of my car]*. Ordinarily this would mean to a point next to the front part of your car.

Comment: @AdilAli as StoneyB stated, if something is located before, ahead of, previous to (someone or something) it takes *in front of*.

Comment: It could be out from a _building_, as you suggest, but, without any more context, my first guess would probably be the _sidewalk_.